# Как получить id из динамического url'а для моего ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, url

Ситуация такова: есть кнопка поста, при клике на которую происходит переход по ссылке на страницу с генерируемым в зависимости от самого поста  id-шником

`<a href="post.php?post_id=<?=$post["id"]?>">  <button   class="more" onclick="getData()">READ ALL</button> </a>`

и мне нужно написать GET ajax запрос для получения контента из этой страницы, но я столкнулся с проблемой незнания того, как сформировать url так, чтобы учитывался ещё и id поста

```
  function getData() {
  
  const requestURL = 'post.php?post_id=' ;  // Здесь мне нужно добавить к url генерируемый id в зависимости от кликнутого поста

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', requestURL);
  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.status !== 200) {
      return;
    }
   
    document.querySelector('.wrapper').innerHTML = xhr.response;
    
  }
  
  xhr.send();

}
```

Вот сама php страница поста:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        


<?php


 include 'database.php';

 include 'functions.php';


$post_id = $_GET["post_id"];

$post = get_post_by_id($post_id);



?>

<div class="main__post_page">

         <div class="close" onclick="closes()"></div>

        <div class="title_name"><?=$post['title']?></div>
        <div class="post_image"><img src="<?=$post['image']?>" alt=""></div>
        
        <div class="down"> 
         <div class="post_description"><?=$post['content']?></div>
                                                                              </div>
```

Comment: Вот здесь ты одинаковыми кавычками запутаешь компилятор `<a href="post.php?post_id=<?=$post["id"]?>"> ` И знак равенства там зачем?. Нужно например так: `<a href="post.php?post_id=<?$post['id']?>"> `. И откуда у тебя тут берётся `$post['id']`? Его так же и подставляй в `requestURL`.

Comment: По поводу вашего предложения убрать знак равенства - это нарушает sql синтаксис что приводит просто к ошибке,поэтому он там должен быть.   $post['id'] это переменная, взятая из ассоциативного массива таблицы post в моей базе данных.   По поводу php переменной $post['id'] в js - я пробовал её передать через атрибут html элемента но url подгружал мне только 1-ый  id

Comment: Ваша функция на JS должна начать принимать параметр, что бы его можно было использовать `function getData(id) { const requestURL = 'post.php?post_id=' + id`. И передать этот id с кнопки, `<button   class="more" onclick="getData(<?=$post["id"]?>)">READ ALL</button>` Правда не ясно зачем вам тогда нужен `<a>`, вы уж определитесь, вы свой php вызываете по ссылке или через ajax

Comment: про тег 'a' я знаю, просто его на время для наглядности добавил, а по поводу решения с передачей id кнопки оно впринципе работает, за что я очень благодарен, но теперь vs code выдаёт ложную ошибку синтаксиса подсвечивая параметр красным, случаем не знаете как это исправить?